# Cache the client connection with ElasticSearch Nest so the first call to the client is fast

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm about to set up suggestion search for ElasticSearch with the NEST client.  Ideally I'd start matching as of the 2nd character entered. However, it takes 600ms the first time I call the client.  Every subsequent call is more like 20ms.  Is there a way to cache or prepare the NEST client?

I've read this post: [Elasticsearch and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004000/)

I've also read that I can either create a new client or use the same instance of the client with no repercussions.

I just want to get the client ready for use before I call it so the user isn't waiting for the client to validate itself.

For the moment I'm making a connection to the client as soon as the user hits the website, then saving the client reference in the session.  However, the first search is still slow even though I've already established the connection.  Is there a way to preload/cache the connection so the delay occurs during page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first hit cache built up is per AppDomain. So you do not need to cache the client itself. Every client you are going to instantiate after the first hit is going to be `warm`.

I've opened up a working ticket so you are able to initiate the warmup process in your application startup so you are no longer penalizing the first user of your system with the warmup costs.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/742

Comment: Since it's per appdomain, this problem will only exist in a development environment. Affecting the very first user in a production environment is a very small concern for me if the rest have no delay.

Comment: Great to hear Brandon, I'm still moving ahead with implementing a warmer that you can place in your program/websites bootstrap process. Will make performance reasoning with your own code a tad easier.